# Instagram feed token keeps expiring

Tags: instagram

I added instagram feed to my website with following way. This works fine but my access token is expiring again and again which results in blank page. Token expiration leads me to generate token manually and so many times.

Can anyone help me out to rectify this problem?

`$result = file_get_contents('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=[my access token]&count=20');`

`$result = json_decode($result);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, this is expected:

*Even though our access tokens do not specify an expiration time, your app should handle the case that either the user revokes access, or Instagram expires the token after some period of time. If the token is no longer valid, API responses will contain an “error_type=OAuthAccessTokenException”. In this case you will need to re-authenticate the user to obtain a new valid token. In other words: do not assume your access_token is valid forever.*

https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/

Is your app in sandbox mode? Maybe in sandbox mode the token lasts less than normal. But still, you shouldn't assume a minimum duration like the above explains.